# How to remove n number of characters of a string in R after a specific character?

Tags: r, stringr

My data frame is:

```
df <- data.frame(player = c("Taiwo Awoniyi/e5478b87", "Jacob Bruun Larsen/4e204552", "Andi Zeqiri/d01231f0"), goals = c(2,5,7))
```

I want to remove all numbers after the "/" in the "player" column. To ideally have:

```
df <- data.frame(player = c("Taiwo Awoniyi", "Jacob Bruun Larsen", "Andi Zeqiri"), goals = c(2,5,7))
```

I am unsure of how to approach this since player names vary greatly in length and some numbers are larger than others.

Comment: Could you please add what has failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `separate`, added  `extra = 'drop'` (many thanks to Onyambu)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(player, "player", sep="/", extra = 'drop')
```

```
              player goals
1      Taiwo Awoniyi     2
2 Jacob Bruun Larsen     5
3        Andi Zeqiri     7
```

Comment: `df %>% 
  separate(player, "player", sep="/", extra = 'drop')`

Comment: Many thanks. you are right Onyambu!

Answer (score 5):

You can backreference the substring you want to keep by a negative character class allowing any characters except the `/`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(player = sub("([^/]+).*", "\\1", player))
              player goals
1      Taiwo Awoniyi     2
2 Jacob Bruun Larsen     5
3        Andi Zeqiri     7
```

More simply, you can just remove anything that's a `/` or a digit:

```
df %>%
  mutate(player = gsub("[/0-9]", "", player))
```

In `base R` syntax:

```
df$player <- gsub("[/0-9]", "", df$player)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr` for the pipe and `mutate`, we can `gsub` everything after `/`.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(player = gsub("\\/.*", "", player))
              player goals
1      Taiwo Awoniyi     2
2 Jacob Bruun Larsen     5
3        Andi Zeqiri     7
```

Answer (score 4):

Using base R.

```
transform(df, player=gsub('/.+', '', player))
#               player goals
# 1      Taiwo Awoniyi     2
# 2 Jacob Bruun Larsen     5
# 3        Andi Zeqiri     7
```